# Difference between services and models in angular 7helli

Tags: angular, service, model

I'm new to angular 
I've followed few tutorials here and there building small apps to do app etc.

Some of these tutorials uses services to inject data to components and use theirs methodes too.
And others uses models to do so.
I'm confused  about the differences  and which one to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the Model-View-Controller architecture.
Models, represent your objects (which attributs do your objects has)
Services are the Controller layer, this means that they contain the logic.